# Set hidden text in a column of a Word Table using VBA without using "select"

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to hide the text of a column in a word table

I use the following (working) code but I wonder if it's possible to avoid using "select"

```
wTbl.Columns(5).Select
Selection.Font.Hidden = True
```

Answer (score 1):

- `Column` object doesn't have `Range` property, so `wtbl.Columns(5).Range.Font.Hidden = True` doesn't work.
- A workaround solution to avoid using `select`, although I don't see the advantage compared to the code in your post.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim wtbl As Table, c As Cell
    Set wtbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    For Each c In wtbl.Columns(5).Cells
        c.Range.Font.Hidden = True
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I was looking for something else, anyway thanks (+1)